# Mixpanel get user id, email and other info via javascript for rails 5 app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, analytics, mixpanel

I'm trying to implement mixpanel in my rails app through their javascript code, and here's what I have so far. I managed to get page view tracking working, but I am unable to track individual users.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    mixpanel.track('page viewed', {
      'page name' : document.title,
      'url' : window.location.pathname
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
mixpanel.people.set({
    '$first_name' : user.first_name,
    '$last_name' : user.last_name,
    '$created' : user.created_at,
    '$email' :  user.email,
    '$user_id' : user.id
});
</script>
```

How can I make it so that Mixpanel correctly sets people to track them by their user id, email, etc?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to login to Mixpanel then Navigate to Users >> Explore tab you can see the list of fields there. You can also create new profile in Mixpanel.